# Is it possible to exclude some folders on the sd card from being added to my playlist in the standard android player?

Tags: media-player

I use the android media player to listen to music. Last week I installed an app that brings a lot of sounds with it in mp3 format and saves them on the SD Card to prevent the app from cluttering my internal memory. Now the media player picked up this folder and added it to my playlist. Every time I listen in shuffle mode I hear a sound from this Application mixed in at least every tenth song I listen to.

Is it possible to exclude a folder from being indexed by the media player?

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it it's possible to add a **.nomedia** file into a folder that you want to exclude from media scans. I've not had occasion to test this myself but the comments on this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3129) seems to confirm that it works.

Comment: seems to work :)

Comment: works, after rescanning media

Comment: You can use [File Expert](https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert) to create the file - long-pressing on a folder gives a menu with option for hiding media. I'm sure there are also other apps that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Meridian Media Player (free in the Market) specifically facilitates this, allows digging deep into a folder structure and other goodies too.